# Initialize a record storage with command line

Tags: smart-contracts, ligo

I'm trying to initialize the storage of the record through the command line. I'm trying different variations of: "ligo compile-storage college.religo main 4  Adam  1600"
For a record called applicant with a return of:
Invalid command line argument.
The provided storage does not have the correct type for the contract.
in file "college.religo", line 21, character 11 to line 30, character 1
Invalid type(s).
Expected: "record[gpa -> int , name -> string , satscore -> int]", but got: "int".

So, when I input: ligo compile-storage  college.religo main record[gpa -> 4 , name -> Adam , satscore -> 1600]
I get back: zsh: bad pattern: [gpa

This is the Usage: ligo compile-storage [OPTION]... SOURCE_FILE ENTRY_POINT STORAGE_EXPRESSION

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

All the best - Adam

Comment: Can you give the type of your storage, or if possible, a link to the full source code of the contract?

Comment: Hi Arvidj, Thank you so much for taking the time to help me. This is it: https://gitlab.com/adamshinder/first-dapp
I found that the correct syntax is: `ligo compile-storage college.religo main {gpa:0 , satscore:0, name:”” }` but it still doesn’t initialize the storage to those values. This is the error message I receive, `ligo: too many arguments, don't know what to do with 'satscore:0', 'gpa:0' `
In the ide.ligolang.org, `{name:"",satscore:0, gpa:0}` this worked as a parameter when running a dry-run,  for a friend of mine but not on my IDE. I’m still having trouble initializing a value.

Comment: Have you tried `ligo compile-storage college.religo main '{gpa:0 , satscore:0, name:"" }'` ? I.e. putting the value of the storage in quotes.

Comment: It worked!! Thank you so much. I really appreciate the help!!